# Twitter Bootstrap based page widget styling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a page based on Twitter Bootstrap > http://wacico.com/carousel-01.htm

I need to get the cartoon strip to display nicely with either a 1px margin or 0px margin between each image.

This seems to be something I need to add further info to the second stylesheet I have for the cartoon widget (which will also be converted and used as a WordPress widget later) but I am not sure how to do this and which would be the best way to do this?

I am trying to have the cartoon strip display so it fits the width as six for desktops and acts responsively for mobiles and am not even sure my use of centering things is all that correct either?

My thinking is I might need to have what is presently marked as adverts above and below the carton strip display as also within the same article code - if that makes sense?

Can anyone help please? There seems to be various ways to do this but which is best especially which will best then work as part of a WP widget?

Comment: Please, create a simpler example that shows the problem and post in jsFiddle.

Comment: I have never used jsfiddle, I thought thta was for .JS things? I could (I think) try to style things using > http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html#variablesbut it seems like an awfully over complicated way to do things as my thinking is to then just take the CSS elements needed and add them to my cartoon-widget CSS but there must me a less complicated way to do this I am sure

Comment: First of all, in a `.container-fluid` you need a `.row-fluid` not a simple row. Secondly if you are talking about removing space between the images "What", "About" etc (which is very unclear), you shouldn't use `span`s. Lastly, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) allows you to share and work on html too. Please use it putting only the relevant code.

Comment: OK I looked at jsfiddle and there looks to be a learning curve to use it as well as a sign up so have tried to find a solution myself and now just need to work out how to make the cartoon strip fit across a screen with all six plates/frames as if I try to add a 960 width to things it then make parts unresponsive and if I try em's that doesn't work either. Anyone an idea at all?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HostTed/jZunf/ OK so I have attempted to show the coed on jsfiddle but tbh I doubt I have listed it right nor will it make any more sense.  Or does it?  That's the html and CSS I need to make responsive (just to stack) for screens EG I think to use the @media query.

Comment: But I need the links above and below each image for 960 width and for the stacking at 3/2 2/3 or 6/1 stacking. Bearing mind that 100% widht can't be used for 960 as pages might be 940, 960, 1000 or other width yet strip must be 960 overall width as there is 156px width per image with 1px in between each image leaving only 13px so perhaps a 5px margin each side of the six images leaving 3px we seem to have spare. Make sense?

Comment: That code on jsfiddle is not working btw but what I am attempting to adapt is so it displays like here > http://tted.co.uk/ only to stack as I use responsive (but not responsive on images as they are fine and dandy at 156px width) - can anyone make sense of this?  I have tried paying two people and asked others but nobody seems to be getting it yet!